# Add apk to appbundle

Tags: android, flutter, android-app-bundle

I have developed a Wear OS app using Flutter. The *flutter build appbundle* command created an appbundle. The app is available on Google Play.
I have also developed a clockface using Watch Face Studio. Using this I can create an apk which I can install on the watch using *adb install*. I can also create an appbundle and make the watch face available on Google Play.
The app and the watchface are signed using the same keystore.
The user can install first the app and then the clock face from Google Play. But to make it easier for the user, I would like to add the clockface to the Flutter app in such a way that the user only has to install the app and get the clockface at the same time. How could that be done? I looked at bundletool but I don't think it solves the problem.